# Dynamically Add TimeStamps to each jpeg images that is used to create a video

Tags: ffmpeg

using ffmpeg and C# I create video files from jpeg images stored on my harddrive.

So, these jpeg images can be in many different locations so I create a fiel called:

```
Test.txt
```

and inside that file I write the jpegs I want to use in the new video file I am creating:

```
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110405363.0.1.1.10.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.5
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110405491.0.1.1.12.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.128
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110405619.0.1.1.12.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.128
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110406594.0.1.1.16.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.975
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110406708.0.1.1.24.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.114
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110406787.0.1.1.05.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.079
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110406923.0.1.1.05.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.136
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110407434.0.1.1.05.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.511
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110407446.0.1.1.05.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.012
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110407575.0.1.1.05.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.129
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110407699.0.1.1.05.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.124
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110407827.0.1.1.36.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.128
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110407963.0.1.1.35.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.136
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110408091.0.1.1.24.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.128
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110408223.0.1.1.00.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.132
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110408347.0.1.1.00.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
duration 0.124
file 'D:\TestPi\Library\DESKTOP-L3DDUI8\2022\02\12\11\04\20220212110408574.0.1.1.00.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg'
```

Then I execute this command line action:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat  -safe 0 -i Test.txt -pix_fmt yuv420p Test.mp4
```

This all works very well.  But not I am looking at wring a timestamp onto each jpeg iamge.

The TimeStamp is part of the file name of each jpeg:

```
20220212110405363.0.1.1.10.efab8311-b8d9-4abf-a9d4-c67a65a9b827.jpg
```

So this bit:

```
20220212110405363
```

is the timestamp for that image.

```
2022     Year
02       Month
12       Day
11       Hour
04       Minute
05       Second
363      Millisecond
```

Is there a way I can modify my script etc to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the timestamp of your image files to the desired in-video timestamp and use the `ts_from_file` option of the `image2` demuxer. You need to do this before running ffmpeg.

Here is [a question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/617392) which relates to your question.

Also, if you haven't read up on it, [here is the image2 documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1)

Comment: Hi. Sorry could not answer yesterday. Thanks for those 2 links I shall see if it gives me anything. If so I will accept your answer.

Comment: Sorry the 1st link had nothing to do with timestamps.  The 2nd link I could see no mention of timestamps in the way i want to use it

Comment: Well, `concat` and `image2` `-ts_from_file` option are the only ways I know of to specify the timestamp. If you aren't willing to do data prep yourself, FFmpeg isn't your answer unfortunately.

Comment: This did not answer my question.  Not a case of the data prep.  It is the User Case that needs to be addressed.